# Distance Matrix HERE API

Tags: here-api

I need to calculate the distance between two postcodes(many to one) so for that, I have integrated Routing API(Matrix of Routes) in our system.

I just notice that calculated distance does not match with the Google Distance Matrix API result.

Example:

```
From PostCode: TR4 8UN(LAT-LONG: 50.28654, -5.15427)
To PostCode: CO11 1QQ(LAT-LONG: 51.95847, 1.06309)
```

HERE API Distance: `335.71689045 Miles`

Google API Distance: `356 Miles`

Supplied following params in the request:

```
Req URL:https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json

Params:mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled;motorway:-2&summaryAttributes=distance
```

Can you please help with this? why it's different? which one is more accurate?

Comment: You can calculate the real distance yourself. I just went to https://www.geodatasource.com/distance-calculator and put your coords there and got the distance of 451 km (293 miles) - which mean both are wrong in respect of geometrical distance. Probably they give distance to get by car or something, which should depend on route choosing. IMHO.

Comment: Well, definitely they use roadway distance, which depends on the quality of underlying database. One can try to make a route manually between two locations and see in different navigational apps...

Comment: thanks, @HeroQu, yes HERE and Google gives Land Transport distance. geodatasource.com/distance-calculator gives straight line(Crow Flies) distance.

I need Land Transport distance

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation:
Summaries of routes in the calculatematrix response are computed using heuristic algorithms optimized for M:N routes computation. They differ from algorithms used in the calculateroute resource therefore the route summary values may also differ to a certain extent.

The underlying algorithm is using heuristic which drives search depending on the number of start/destinations. Different matrix sizes may give different results and this is expected. We are not able to ensure the same results for different sizes of matrices until we use this heuristic.